# How to prove for $s<1,|a+b|^s\le|a|^s+|b|^s$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How to prove for $s<1$$$|a+b|^s\le|a|^s+|b|^s$$ I tried to prove $|a+b|\le (|a|^s+|b|^s)^{\frac{1}{s}}$, but $\frac{1}{s}$ may not be integer, so I do not know how to expand it if it is not integer.

Is it the right way to prove it by trying to expand it using binomial expansion? How to prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do $a$ and $b$ live? Also, do you mean $\left|b\right|^s$ in all instances?

Comment: @Stahl Sorry, that is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for positive $a,b$ and $s \in (0,1)$ 
$$
a^s +b^s = s\left(\int_0^a x^{s-1}dx+\int_0^b x^{s-1}dx \right) \\
\ge  s\left(\int_0^a x^{s-1}dx+\int_0^b (x+a)^{s-1}dx \right) \\
=  s\left(\int_0^a x^{s-1}dx+\int_a^{a+b} x^{s-1}dx \right) \\
=  s\left(\int_0^{a+b}x^{s-1}dx \right) \\
= (a+b)^s
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the function $f(x)=(1+x)^s-1-x^s$ for $x\geq 0$